# AWS Full-Text Search with Elastic: Invalid endpoint provided for external service query

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, gremlin, amazon-neptune, opensearch

Currently I'm playing with AWS ElasticSearch (OpenSearch) on top of AWS Neptune. They are classically integrated through Neptune streams. When I'm trying to execute Gremlin query:

```
t.withSideEffect("Neptune#fts.endpoint", "https://vpc-DOMAIN-ID.REGION.es.amazonaws.com")
  .V()
  .hasLabel("person")
  .has("firstName", "Neptune#fts Viki~")
```

I'm getting Neptune API exception:

```
org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.exception.ResponseException:
{"code":"InvalidParameterException","requestId":"e2427e4a-333d-4952-b8a1-929e7c72fc96","detailedMessage":"Invalid endpoint provided for external service query."}
```

Both Neptune and ElasticSearch reside within the same private subnet. Elastic is configured to use VPC endpoint. Any help would be appreciated, including how to debug/profile such a behaviour etc

Comment: Are you able to connect to the ES endpoint using a basic `curl` command from the same VPC that Neptune and ES are running in? Something like `curl  https://vpc-neptune-abc-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.us-east-1.es.amazonaws.com/amazon_neptune` I would make sure that you can do that before trying to debug the Neptune connection. Also which version of ES are you using, or are you using Open Search?

Comment: @KelvinLawrence Yes, I can make GET requests (https) it returns mapping. I'm using ElasticSearch engine version 7.10 and Neptune engine version 1.0.5.1.

Comment: One other question, did you use the Cloud Formation templates listed at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/neptune/latest/userguide/full-text-search-cfn-create.html to set everything up?